# Disk Utility Restore causes "Could not validate resource - Invalid Argument"

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, restore, disk-utility

I have a problem with Disk Utility on Mac OS X 10.6. I have an image of Windows that I would like to use as a bootable volume on a pen drive or external hard drive. The thing is:

1. When I try to restore the volume from the image I get an error:

   > "Restore Failure: Could not validate resource - Invalid Argument"
2. I read some information about that error on the Internet. I converted the image into .iso (Mac OS Extended/ISO (Joliet) Hybrid Image) format and then got this error:

   > "Restore Failure: Could not find any scan information. The source image needs to be imagescanned before it can be restored."
3. When I try to scan the image for Restore, I get the first message.

I really read a lot of information about this topic on the Internet, but I haven't found the solution.

I tried both ISO and DMG formats; I don't know which is best.

Comment: Is this a Windows install image or a backup image? If it's an install, I'm interested in the answer as well. The only way I was able to do this when I wanted to install Windows on a new netbook was to fire up my Windows 7 in VMware Fusion and use the [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](http://store.microsoft.com/help/iso-tool).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest WinClone, which worked well for me once when I needed to backup a Bootcamp partition. The developer's website is here: http://www.twocanoes.com/winclone/

You can try an older, shareware demo here:
http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/Winclone-Download-27227.html
The third Download Location labeled as "Softpedia Secure Download (RO) [DMG]" appears to be still available.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to create new image from folder (and select the folder with my .iso in it) Then when it was done I had my iso inside a DMG. Then instead of dragging my DMG as the source for restore(image 1) I used the mount folder of that DMG(image 2) and it worked perfectly.

Image 1[image]

Image 2[image]

PS: ended up answering it myself after adding a bounty, funny how that works out.

Comment: So I did this.. and now I have a usb key with a folder with an iso image in it.  What is this good for..?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.